# Threads, atomic boolean, synchronized design considerations for a method that has to wait for a result

Tags: android, json, multithreading, rfcomm, atomicboolean

My code is starting to get a bit hard to debug which leads me to believe that my design choices are not ideal. I am a novice Android programming and would love some help with streamlining the design for optimum operation.

**Intro**

I am writing an application that uses rfcomm interface to transfer data between a client and server device. The client needs to request certain things from the server using a specific key, then it needs to wait until the server sends the result back.

**Current Design**

- A button press triggers a request for information from the server.
- A new thread is started which performs the request.
- A key which is a unique integer is converted to a byte array and sent to the server.
- Thread has a while loop that is waiting for a specific boolean to flip from false to true indicating a response back from the server.
- Information is received on the server side. Server uses key to identify what to do next.
- server starts a thread to run some query and gets a jsonString back as a result.
- Server sends jsonstring converted to byte array prepended with the same identifying key back to the client.
- Client reads message, and sends the byte array to a handling method based on the identifying key.
- Handling method stores jsonString to a class variable and then flips the boolean to let the other thread know that the value it was waiting on has been set.
- Json string is converted to object on the client side. Something is done with that object.

This code currently correctly sends info to the server, server correctly does search and gets a valid json string result. However, the issue occurs when the server writes its results make to the client. I am getting 20 messages instead of one and none match the search key...

**My questions**

- Am I doing things in an efficient way design wise?
- Can I benefit from using `synchronized` keyword or and Atomic Boolean to make my code more thread safe? How would I go about implementing it?
- Is there a max length for converting strings to byte array? Maybe the code is trying to break up the sending for me and that's why I'm getting 20 different results?

**Relevant code**

```
public class ClientSpokesmanClass {

    private final int searchKey = 2222222; //set the key to some int.
    private boolean pendingSearchResults = false;
    List<Place> places = new ArrayList<Place>();

    private final Handler handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){
            switch(msg.what) {
            ...
            case MESSAGE_READ:
                //Message received from server
                readAndDistribute(msg.arg1, msg.obj);
                break;
            ... 
            }
         }
     };

   public List<Place> getPlacesFromServer(String query){
        //ask server for search results
        requestSearchFromServer(query);
        //just wait for them...
        while (pendingSearchResults){
           //just waiting
       }
        return places;
    }

    private void requestSearchFromConnectedDevice(String query) {
        if (mBluetoothState == STATE_CONNECTED){
            byte[] bites = new byte[4];
            bites = ByteBuffer.wrap(bites).putInt(searchKey).array();
            byte[] stringBytes = null;

            try {
                stringBytes = query.getBytes("UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e(TAG, "unsupported encoding", e);
            }

            int keyLength = bites.length;
            int stringLength = stringBytes.length;

            byte[] combined = new byte[keyLength+stringLength];
            System.arraycopy(bites, 0, combined, 0, keyLength);
            System.arraycopy(stringBytes, 0, combined, keyLength, stringLength);

            mBluetoothService.write(combined);
        }

    pendingSearchResults = true;
    }

private void receiveSearchResults(byte[] bites){

    String jsonString = "";
    PlacesJSONParser parser = new PlacesJSONParser();

     try {
         jsonString = new String(bites, "UTF-8");
     } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e(TAG, "unsupported encoding", e);
    }

     if (D) Log.d(TAG, "Json string we got is "+jsonString);

    try {
         places = parser.parse(new JSONObject(jsonString));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e(TAG, "JSON exception", e);
    }
    pendingSearchResults = false;
 }

/**
 * Reads come here first. Then, based on the key prepended to them, 
  * they then go to other methods for further work.
  * @param bytes
  * @param buffer
  */
private synchronized void readAndDistribute(int bytes, Object buffer){

    byte[] buff = (byte[]) buffer;

     int key = ByteBuffer.wrap(Arrays.copyOfRange(buff, 0, 4)).getInt();

     if (key == searchKey){
         receiveSearchResults(Arrays.copyOfRange(buff, 4, bytes));
     }else{
         //do something else
        }
    }
}
```

.

```
public class ClientUI extends Activity {
    ...
    onQueryTextSubmit(String query){
        final String queryFinal = query;
        Thread thread = new Thread(){
            public void run() {
               places = ClientSpokesmanClass.getPlacesFromServer(query);
               doSomethingWithPlaces();
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }

}
```

.

```
public class ServerReceive {
    private searchKey = 2222222;

    ...
    //code that handles messages, reads key, and then runs doSearchAndWriteResults()
    ...

    private synchronized void doSearchAndWriteResults(byte[] bites){
        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "+++writeSearchResults");

        //Initialize query and placesString
        String query = null;
        String placesString;

        //Convert byte array to the query string
        try {
            query = new String(bites, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           Log.e(TAG, "unsupported encoding",e);
        }

        //if the string was converted successfully...
        if (query != null){
            //Run the places query and set the json string to placesString
            if (D) Log.d(TAG, "query is "+query);
            PlacesProvider placeProvider = new PlacesProvider();
            placesString = placeProvider.getPlacesString(query);
        }

        //initialize a bite array
        byte[] stringBytes = null;
        try {
            //convert jsonString to byte array
            stringBytes = placesString.getBytes("UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e(TAG, "unsupported encoding",e);
        }

         //Put the search key to a byte array. I am using this key on the client side
         //to confirm that we are reading searchResults and not some other type of write.
        byte[] bite = new byte[4];
        bite = ByteBuffer.wrap(bite).putInt(searchKey).array();

        //Get the lengths of the two byte arrays
        int keyLength = bite.length;
        int stringLength = stringBytes.length;

        //combine the byte arrays for sending
        byte[] combined = new byte[keyLength+stringLength];
        System.arraycopy(bite, 0, combined, 0, keyLength);
        System.arraycopy(stringBytes, 0, combined, keyLength, stringLength);

        if (D) Log.d(TAG, "Actually writing things here...");

        //send the byte arrrays over rfcomm
        mBluetoothService.write(combined);

     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/gettyimages/connect_sdk_java. Specifically, at the test application. It performs a search using an AsyncTask and the private class notifies the UI via onPostExecute. Hopefully, this will get you further along.

Comment: Thanks for the example! Good pattern to learn from, but it seems that its implementation is an alternative (and probably cleaner) way to do what I was doing. I'm still getting errors. 

Do you know anything about maxlength of strings to send over rfcomm using String.getBytes("UTF-8")?